# How to uncheck a checkbox in array adapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to uncheck checkbox in listview array adapter on onItemClickListener.
its remain checked all the time.If i again click on it to uncheck it is not getting unchecked.
Can anyone over here please suggest me how to do it?

```
 pagesresult = new JSONArray(getIntent().getStringExtra("pageResult"));
                for (int i = 0; i < pagesresult.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = pagesresult.getJSONObject(i);
                    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();

                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        key = keys.next();
                        //pageValue = );
                        pageKeyArray.add(key);
                        pageArray.add(String.valueOf(json.get(key)));
                        System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + json.get(key));
                        Log.d(TAG, "pageKeyArray Check :" + pageKeyArray);
                        Log.d(TAG, "currentKey Check :" + pageArray);
                    }

                }

                alreadyBookedByUser = new JSONArray(getIntent().getStringExtra("alreadyBookedByUser"));
                Log.d(TAG, "compositionCount Check :" + pagesresult);
                Log.d(TAG, "compositionCount Check :" + alreadyBookedByUser);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
            findViewsById();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,pageArray);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == done) {

                SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

                ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                    // Item position in adapter

                    position = checked.keyAt(i);
                    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Position check :" + position);
                    // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!

                    if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                        selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));

                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Page key array show :" + this.pageKeyArray);
                Log.d(TAG, "selectedItems show :" + selectedItems);

                int max = -1;
                for(String value: selectedItems) {
                    int selectedIndex= this.pageArray.indexOf(value);
                    this.selectedPageIems.add(this.pageKeyArray.get(selectedIndex));
                    if(selectedIndex > max) {
                        max = selectedIndex;
                    }
                }
                String firstPageNumber = getFirstPageNumber(this.pageKeyArray.get(0));
                String currentPageNumber = firstPageNumber;
                String lastPageNumber = getLastPageNumber(this.pageKeyArray.get(max));
                Log.d(TAG, "First Page Number :" + firstPageNumber);
                Log.d(TAG, "Last Page Number :" + lastPageNumber);
                Log.d(TAG, "selectedPageIndexes show :" + selectedPageIndexes);
                Log.d(TAG, "selectedPageIems show :" + selectedPageIems);

                String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                    outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
                }
                try {
                    selectPages();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyBookings.class);
                session.setPageNumbers(firstPageNumber,currentPageNumber,lastPageNumber);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "First Page Number :" + position);
            for (int i=0; i<=position; i++){
                listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You check the checkboxes each time you press an item ?

`@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "First Page Number :" + position);
            for (int i=0; i<=position; i++){
                listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
            }
        }`

I don't see setItemChecked(i,false) anywhere

Comment: could you please tell me where should i put this line??

Comment: At the place you want to uncheck the checkbox I guess

Comment: I have to uncheck it onItemclick only...I have tried like this...for (int j=0; j<=position; j++){
            //listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
            listView.setItemChecked(j,false);
        }but it did'nt worked

Comment: Just to be sure doing that you want to uncheck ALL the list checkboxes ?

Comment: lets say there are 4 check boxex,if it is getting unchecked from last(i.e 4) it should uncheck only the clicked item.but if getting unchecked in between like say 2 then it will uncheck all the boxes from 2.(ie: 2,3&4).

Comment: So you should unckeck from Position to (list.size() -1) and not from 0 to position I guess. And force it with checkboxview.invalidate()  maybe... But to be honnest that work should be done inside the Adapter using the Holder pattern

Comment: is there any way to get the state of listItems whether it is checked or not??in current situation